# How to use expires_in in Facebook v4.0 iOS SDK with an Open Graph action?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been migrating to Facebook SDK v4.x to implement an Open Graph story and so far it's been fine, but the problem that I am having is that I used to add a property for the action called "expires_in".

The thing is that I don't really know how to do that with new SDK.

The code that I am using is identical from the tutorial, like this:

```
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"books.reads";
[action setObject:object forKey:@"books:book"];
```

I assumed that I needed to do the following:

```
[action setObject:30 forKey:@"expires_in"];
```

but the "setObject" parameter requires an object of type FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject, which I don't know exactly which parameters will it should get. For example, should I create the object like this?

```
NSDictionary *properties = @{
    @"expires_in": @"30",
};

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *expires_in_object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];
```

Comment: `expires_in` is marked as integer in the docs, so naturally I’d try `setInteger` first … (And if that doesn’t work, I’d try to set it as a string value.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that method is not present. I tried with `setValue:forKey`, `setNumber:forKey`, `setValue:forUndefinedKey` and `setString:forKey` and nothing happened. The action is always in past tense

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working.

I said in a comment above that it didn't work out with `setNumber:forKey` but it finally worked. This is what I use:

```
[action setNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:300] forKey:@"expires_in"];
```